# R string, UTF-8 coding swedish character treatment

Tags: r, string, utf-8, gsub

have problem to change the swedish characters ä ö å in a presentable way in R
I got my data directly from MS SQL database
here are the examples

```
markets <- c("Caf\xe9                          ","Restaurang kv\xe4ll              ","Barnomsorg tillagningsk\xf6k     ","Folkh\xf6gskola                  ")
```

then I use gusb to remove the lefthand space

```
market=gsub(" ", "", markets,fixed = TRUE)
```

I got this error:
Error in gsub(" ", "", market, fixed = TRUE) :
  input string 3 is invalid UTF-8

then I use this command:
   markets_new=gsub(" ", "", markets)

then have strange Chinese characters in the string,
"Caf攼㸹"
"Restauranglunch+kv攼㸴ll"
"Barnomsorgtillagningsk昼㸶k"
"Folkh昼㸶gskola"

I tried the treatment change the default setting of Rstudio by following:
https://yihui.name/en/2018/11/biggest-regret-knitr/?fbclid=IwAR2E5Lp0zjS51fcdjgZ1tej0sg5EBxfG8sNitt-cUA2XEshnT3lNCHNQ3Do

it does not help, was also try to use gsub() substitute the characters but seems not working.

One more thing, if I use

```
write.csv(markets,'submarket product view.csv',row.names = F)
```

then in my csv file what I see as follows

```
"Caf<e9>                          "
"Restaurang kv<e4>ll              "
"Barnomsorg tillagningsk<f6>k     "
"Folkh<f6>gskola                  "
"Sm<f6>rg<e5>s/salladsrestaurang     "
```

I think `<e9>` is e with a hat, `<e4>` is ä, `<f6>` is ö, and `<e5>` is å
Any treatment suggestion?

Comment: Try `Encoding(markets)<-"latin1"`.

Comment: It works fine as is in my Windows RGui 3.4.3 build. The problem is most likely with the locale.

Comment: ``gsub(" ", "", `Encoding<-`(markets, "latin1"),fixed = TRUE)`` should work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: it not really work, when I use that commend for one column in data frame or tibble I got the result:Cafæ”¼ã¸¹ ** , **Restaurangostorkæ˜¼ã . but it works if I only apply on it on this character vector. Any more suggestion? thank you!

Comment: Provide [reproducible data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: hi Wiktor, her is the code:

m <- c("Caf\xe9                          ","Barnomsorg tillagningsk\xf6k     ","Folkh\xf6gskola                  ","\xd6vriga stork\xf6k                ")
date <- c(as.Date('2016-12-26'), as.Date('2016-12-23'),as.Date('2017-01-19'),as.Date('2017-01-02'))
number <- rnorm(4)

df <- data.frame(m,date,number)  ###also can try, dt=as_tibble(df) also
t <- df %>% 
  mutate(market=gsub(" ", "", `Encoding<-`(m,"latin1"),fixed = TRUE)) and will be nice to have know how to understand `Encoding<-`(markets, "latin1") 
 commend

Comment: ``df$m <- gsub(" ", "", `Encoding<-`(as.character(df$m), "latin1"),fixed = TRUE)`` works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Wiktor Stribiżew
this solution works best:

```
df$m <- gsub(" ", "", `Encoding<-`(as.character(df$m), "latin1"),fixed = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Encoding(markets) <- "UTF-16"
markets <- trimws(markets)

#[1] "Café" "Restaurang kväll" "Barnomsorg tillagningskök" "Folkhögskola"
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, while `latin1` works, as I said in the comments.

Comment: @nicola weird.. works just fine for me. Any ideas why? selected locale?

Comment: Not really. It seems very strange that something like `UTF-16` might work here (as far as I know, `UTF-16` wants two bytes for character).

Comment: Thank you for the input. I tried both. if treat 'markets' as  "character" vector. both `latin1` and `UTF-16`. But currently I have a column in tibble format called 'market' has this issue. the I tried   `test <- dfp %>% head(100) %>% mutate(mar=gsub(" ", "", `Encoding<-`(market, "UTF-16"),fixed = TRUE))`  or `test <- dfp %>% head(100) %>% mutate(mar=gsub(" ", "", `Encoding<-`(market, "latin1"),fixed = TRUE))`    they have same results, when I use head(test): I see ** Cafæ”¼ã¸¹ ** , **Restaurangostorkæ˜¼ã ** in the console. any more suggestion?